# Why does not this for-loop work?

Tags: loops

Help, please.

This code does't work:

```java
for (i = 0; i == userWhoIsInLineArray.GetNumberOfUsersOnline() - 1; i++) {
    Log.d("DATA-----|", "UserName- "
        + userWhoIsInLineArray.GetUserName(i)
        + "   UserHref- "
        + userWhoIsInLineArray.GetUserAccountHref(i));
}
```

When I write this one, all work!

```java
while(i != userWhoIsInLineArray.GetNumberOfUsersOnline() - 1) {
    Log.d("DATA-----|", "UserName- "
        + userWhoIsInLineArray.GetUserName(i)
        + "   UserHref- "
        + userWhoIsInLineArray.GetUserAccountHref(i));
    i++;
}
```

Why is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you meant to use equality in your for loop test for continuance?

This bit:

```
i == userWhoIsInLineArray.GetNumberOfUsersOnline()-1
```

Perhaps you meant another comparison operator?

Answer (score 0):

You should write as:

```java
for (i = 0; i < userWhoIsInLineArray.GetNumberOfUsersOnline(); i++) {
    Log.d("DATA-----|", "UserName- "
        + userWhoIsInLineArray.GetUserName(i)
        + "   UserHref- "
        + userWhoIsInLineArray.GetUserAccountHref(i));
}
```

Only when the second sentence of for-clause is true, for-block is executed. So, when the variable `i` is **smaller than** `userWhoIsInLineArray.GetNumberOfUsersOnline()`, it must be true.

cf 1. `i == userWhoIsInLineArray.GetNumberOfUsersOnline()` means only when variable `i` equals `userWhoIsInLineArray.GetNumberOfUsersOnline()` it is true. Unless `userWhoIsInLineArray.GetNumberOfUsersOnline()` is `0`, it results false for the first loop.

cf 2. In the same sence your while-loop is better to rewrite as:

```java
int i = 0;
while (i < userWhoIsInLineArray.GetNumberOfUsersOnline()) {
    Log.d("DATA-----|", "UserName- "
        + userWhoIsInLineArray.GetUserName(i)
        + "   UserHref- "
        + userWhoIsInLineArray.GetUserAccountHref(i));
    i++;
}
```